# Mockito reset injected fields in the course of a test?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, spy

I suspect I may be told that I need to redesign my test or my app class or something... but who knows, maybe not?

I have a CUT I'm testing with an injected spy `java.util.Properties` field `mockedProps`, standing in for field `Properties props` ...

Supposing in the course of its activities (e.g. in a functional or E2E test rather than a super-simple unit test) the CUT sets the value of the field `props` to a newly created `Properties` object. This makes this new field no longer accessible from the test method.

It would be nice to be able to say "reinject" the current `props` field as `mockedProps` ... is there any way of doing this or some technique that addresses this sort of problem?

Comment: Why would you mock a Properties object rather than using/modifying a real one? And if your class-under-test changes which instance it's pointing to, then how is that Properties class any more than a private implementation detail that is insulated from external changes (like the ones you seem to be trying to simulate)?

Comment: Thanks. At the moment there is little direct access from outside the CUT to this Properties object... I'd have to introduce a getter + setter specifically for testing purposes, which probably isn't desirable, right? I'm going to have to think about your other point: the thing I'm trying to do is to simulate reading in (`load` from a file) properties which are in some way wrong, and making sure the CUT responds correctly.  No doubt I'm trying to do too many things at once.  But it is a "functional" test rather than a unit test...